# SQL syntax error when selecting from tables in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `lg3ni_k2_favorites` AS faves, 
>   `lg3ni_k2_items` AS items, WHERE (faves.user' at line 1 SQL=SELECT faves.item_id AS item_id,
>   items.title AS items_name, FROM `lg3ni_k2_favorites` AS faves, `lg3ni_k2_items` AS items, 
>   WHERE (faves.user_id='349') AND (faves.item_id = items.id)

From the syntax:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = "SELECT faves.item_id AS item_id, items.title AS items_name, ";
    $query .= "FROM `#__k2_favorites` AS faves, `#__k2_items` AS items, ";
    $query .= "WHERE (faves.user_id='".intval($userID)."') ";
    $query .= "AND (faves.item_id = items.id) ";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $ff = $db->loadObjectList();
    echo $db->getErrorMsg();
    return $ff;
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Problem is the unnecessary `,` before `FROM`

Comment: removed but still get the  same error.

Comment: Similarly remove `,` before `WHERE`. Do remember to leave space as-is, that is dont remove the space when removing `,`.

Comment: removed both comma , i dont get data from databases

Comment: any new error message?

Comment: If `faves.user_id` is an integer then remove the single quotes `'` from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: none just empty table '<table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>'

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma after `items_name,`,another extra comma after `AS items`

```
 $query = "SELECT faves.item_id AS item_id, items.title AS items_name ";
 $query .= "FROM `#__k2_favorites` AS faves, `#__k2_items` AS items ";
```

Answer (score 0):

remove comma from both below queries

```
$query = "SELECT faves.item_id AS item_id, items.title AS items_name ";
    $query .= "FROM `#__k2_favorites` AS faves, `#__k2_items` AS items ";
```

Comment: removed both comma , i dont get data from databases ??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();   
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('faves.item_id') . ' AS ' . $db->quoteName('item_id') . ',' . $db->quoteName('items.title') . ' AS ' . $db->quoteName('items_name')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_favorites') . ' AS ' . $db->quoteName('faves') . ',' . $db->quoteName('#__k2_items') . ' AS ' . $db->quoteName('items'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('faves.user_id') . ' = '. $db->quote(intval($userID)) . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('faves.item_id') . ' = '. $db->quote('items.id'));     
$db->setQuery($query);

$ff = $db->loadObjectList();
```

This uses Joomla coding standards, however please note that I haven't tested it so let me know if it works or not.